# How to store some info while user is submitting rating with Fivestar module?

Tags: forms, ajax, rating

I want to store this rating on different site and I am doing this with the help of RESTful api. I have altered "fivestar_custom_widget" form with hook_form_alter. My call is not working beacuse it is not removing div which has 'field-name-field-fivestar-rating' class and not adding div which has 'rating-wrapper' id.

```
function recipe_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'fivestar_custom_widget') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'fivestar_rest_api';
  }
}

function fivestar_rest_api($form, $form_state) {
   $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $json = json_decode($data,true);
   $errorMessage = $json['errorMessage'];
   $errorCode = $json['errorCode'];
   $commands[] = ajax_command_remove('.field-name-field-fivestar-rating');
   $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#rating-wrapper', 'Thankyou for your rating.');
   return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submit handler was not working so I have decide to do it with validate handler like this

```
 
function recipe_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'fivestar_custom_widget') {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'fivestar_rest_api';
  }
}

function fivestar_rest_api($form, $form_state) {
   $ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/xxx");
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $data = curl_exec($ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   $json = json_decode($data,true);
   $errorMessage = $json['errorMessage'];
   $errorCode = $json['errorCode'];
   $commands[] = ajax_command_remove('.field-name-field-fivestar-rating');
   $commands[] = ajax_command_append('#rating-wrapper', 'Thankyou for your rating.');
   return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
 }
```

Now it is working fine form me.